# VS2017 fail to expand parameter pack with error "parameter pack must be expanded in this context"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Here is an extracted simple example of the problem:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/container.hpp>

template <typename... Args>
auto func(Args&&... a)
{
    boost::fusion::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(a)>::type...> vec(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)...);
    // use vec...
}

int main()
{
    func(12, "str", 3.3);
}
```

The code compiles with gcc-4.8/clang-3.5, but fails to compile with VS 2017 with error:

error C3520: 'a': parameter pack must be expanded in this context

Am i missing something MS specific here?

Comment: As a workaround, using `Args` instead of `decltype(a)` should work.

Comment: ^That, and you forgot that you are using the best standard conformant compiler there is and ever will be. I think.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you try `std::decay_t<decltype(a)>...` instead?

Comment: @Angew - this workaround works, thanks

Comment: @StoryTeller  - no - the problem remains, and also std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)... fails to compile too.